# ffmpegthumbnailer error - Failed to load gio libraries (Kubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu

I have installed `ffmpegthumbnailer` in Kubuntu 14.04 by typing

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

This is the output of `ffmpegthumbnailer -v`:

```
ffmpegthumbnailer version: 2.0.8
```

Whenever I try to create thumbnails by running

```
ffmpegthumbnailer -i "input file.mp4" -o out.png
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to load gio libraries
```

The thumbnail is created however. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by running

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

Inspired by [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/281987/585252) answer.