# Native dependency gio-2.0 found: NO. Found '2.40.2' but need: '>= 2.53.2' when building gnome-builder

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

During the building of gnome-builder on Ubuntu 14.04 I have encountered this message.

Obviously gio is installed but when trying to install or upgrade this package, package is nowhere to be found. Some sources call this gio-unix-2.0

What would be correct repository and package name to upgrade to get to a new version?

### Update 16-sep-17

Possible duplicate on: [How Install gio-unix-2.28.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281984/how-install-gio-unix-2-28-0)

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

results to:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Recipe therefore do not apply. If one observes versions 2.28 is way old version we are here at current version 2.40 and desired upgrade to minimum 2.53. apt-get obviously resolves to gio 2.40 as the most recent (at least thru installation of libglib2.0-dev).

On other note, if I knew which PPA to use I would likely solve the problem. But I cannot find appropriate library that contains gio 2.53 AND that works on 14.04. THIS IS A QUESTION: what to install to get this working (if possible/available at all).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Install gio-unix-2.28.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281984/how-install-gio-unix-2-28-0)

Comment: When compiling from source you need the -dev packages as they contain the headers. Use google to identify them if you do not know already - If you need a version not in the repos , well you need to find a ppa or compile that from source as well

Comment: looks like that only 'artful' release contains libglib2 library v2.53, not even 'xenial' has version this high. see:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libglib2.0-dev

Comment: so yes you have to download and compile 2.53 or higher.

Comment: Building GLIB looks extremely complex, it is not documented enough (building process), many exotic (to me) tools are needed (installed some of them e.g. automake, meson) but even with them some lib dependences are not resolved and it gets even more puzzling. At this stage it would be better if someone with more experience builds this (if this is possible at all, as I have previously mentioned)

Comment: If someone else is looking sources are here: https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.53/  but I do not know how to compile it.

Comment: The joys of not using apt. This is why package managers were designed.

Comment: "This is why package managers were designed." - Yeah they are wonderfully great until some point. Then, you wish to do something else, that is not mainstream thinking, and suddenly contra all expectations in 7 or 8 billion souls world, you find yourself alone. Why did you choose that path? Perhaps sometimes for a cause. I think at this point that I would give up and re-visit subject in some future. It worked in the past. The future will make it or break it.

Comment: Took me a while but I got some hints: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2017-August/msg00028.html

Comment: Well, you can always go with arch , gentoo, or linux from scratch if you want more control over your system. Of the 3 only LFS has no package manager by default. Of the 3 I prefer gentoo, although it does have a package manager you can micromanage most aspects. See http://bodhizazen.com/img/Linux/gentoo.png

Comment: Although I use to be more down to metal in early years of computers, nowadays I am more interested in other more higher level aspects of programming. For example this interest is driven by getting gnome-builder to functional state (gnome builder at least recent versions are not available for moderately old Ubuntu). But even that is not my real target. My real target is Vala and Genie which are somewhat oldish on current Ubuntu for which I managed to push higher to most recent installation and it seems working. Some people claim that these projects are dead (or that they are struggling).

Comment: Final verdict on this attempt: I managed to completely mess up my Ubuntu and abandoned the further actions on trying to make it working in order to have gnome builder. I have recovered my installation close to original after much pain (and lot of learning on what to do and not to do), thus piece of advice for other hackers: Better do not do it.
I am however amazed with Ubuntu's installation resilience, although I have learned how fragile whole system is, I still managed to recover most of the installation. And I must say I do not regret trying it in spite of falling. Learning made it worth.